# How to specify default CREATE TABLE values just once?

Tags: sqlite, table, datatypes, default-value, empty-string

Is there any way I can just say once that the default type should be TEXT, and the
default value should be '' for all CREATE TABLEs?
Currently I must do:

```
CREATE TABLE "t" (dbm TEXT DEFAULT '', rsrp TEXT DEFAULT '', cdma TEXT DEFAULT ''...
```

(I'm using sqlite3.)

Comment: No, as you can see in the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html).

Comment: Note if every column of every table of yours is just the TEXT data type, there's a good chance you're doing something wrong design-wise and should re-evaluate your schema.